# How I get a variable defined in for loop outside in the loop? -Python

Tags: python

When I run this Python code I get a NameError. But in this code I'm trying to get a variable defined in a for loop **(get)** to use in outside of the loop. How can I use this variable **(get)** outside in for loop?

```
file = open("f:/py/price.txt", "r")

valRange = 0
cal = 0
totalCst = 0
itmCnt = 0
while (valRange < 10):
     idNumber = int(input("Enter Id number: "))
     for line in file:
          if line.startswith(str(idNumber)):
               get = line.split("=")[1]
          break
     quantity = int(input("Enter qantity: "))
     cal = quantity * int(get)
     totalCst += cal
     itmCnt += quantity

print (totalCst)
```

Comment: You don't need to anything extra.  Maybe nothing ever gets assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize the variable before the loop. Also the `break` command was out of the `if`.
Try:

```
file = open("f:/py/price.txt", "r")

valRange = 0
cal = 0
totalCst = 0
itmCnt = 0
while (valRange < 10):
     idNumber = int(input("Enter Id number: "))
     get = 0
     for line in file:
          if line.startswith(str(idNumber)):
               get = line.split("=")[1]
               break
     quantity = int(input("Enter qantity: "))
     cal = quantity * int(get)
     totalCst += cal
     itmCnt += quantity

print (totalCst)
```

Comment: It worked. But I've found some errors in my script. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to mark the answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Indent the `break` more.

```
 for line in file:
      if line.startswith(str(idNumber)):
           get = line.split("=")[1]
           break
```

Also what if there are no matching lines? `get` won't have a value then. Make sure you skip the subsequent code if no lines matched.